# Maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have a C# 4.0 console app that calls a WCF Web Service which lives inside an ASP.net 4.0 Web Site.  When the web service is called, I get this error :

```
The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: 
Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'AddArticle'. 
The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while 
reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the 
MaxStringContentLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object 
used when creating the XML reader. 
Line 60, position 267.
```

So looking around it seems that you need to increase the maxStringContentLength and maxReceivedMessageSize properties within the config files to a large number.  I have done this but still receive the error.

The config from my console app is :

```
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IXXXInterface" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="5242880" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://axa-ppp/webservices/xxxinterface.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IXXXInterface" contract="XXX_YYYY_Interface.IXXXInterface" name="BasicHttpBinding_IXXXInterface"/>
    </client>
```

The config from the website is :

```
      <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IXXXInterface" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="5242880" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
          <security mode="None">
              <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
              <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
          </security>
      </binding>
```

and

```
    <endpoint address="http://xxx-ppp/webservices/xxxinterface.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IXXXInterface" contract="XXX_YYYY_Interface.IXXXInterface" name="BasicHttpBinding_IXXXInterface"/>
```

**EDIT:**

This is the class file on the Website :

```
public class XXXInterface : IXXXInterface
{

public bool AddArticle(string Title, string ArticleXml)
{
    ContentData article = new ContentData();
    article.Title = Title;
    article.Html = ArticleXml;
    article.FolderId = 320;

    ContentData newArticle = contentMgr.Add(article);

    if (newArticle == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }        
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried increasing the maxItemsInObjectGraph on the behaviour element as well as the HttpRunTime maxRequestLength property both on server and client

Comment: Hi Rajesh, I just tried that but I still get the same result.

Comment: Can you post your servers service elements and your interface class

Comment: Can you post the config entry of the service element on the server web.config file

Comment: Hi Rajesh, I have already posted the server config above where it says the "config from the website is:".  Unless you mean something else?  I don't think there is anything else that is relevant.

Comment: Your binding configurations for the service & client sides looks correct. Are you certain the config settings are actually being used for configuration of the client? It seems from the exception text that the error is occurring on the client side.

Comment: No I'm not 100% certain.  The error is thrown from the console app.  I have actually duplicated the config across both the console app and the Website.

Comment: I also have tried upping the maxAllowedContentLength in System.webServer > Security > requestFiltering.

Comment: And I have set maxRequestLength, requestLengthDiskThreshold to maximum int32 value in System.Web > httpRuntime.  All to no avail.

Comment: For info, I have now given up on WCF and re-written the web service as SOAP instead.  It works perfectly.  Should have stuck to the simple stuff in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem! :D

The problem is in `IdBookIssuerIssuedTokenBinding.CreateBindingElements()`.

I had overridden and not called the base:

```
public override BindingElementCollection CreateBindingElements()
{
    BindingElementCollection elements = new BindingElementCollection();

    elements.Add(this.security);
    elements.Add(this.transport);

    return elements;
}
```

Now I am doing this:

```
public override BindingElementCollection CreateBindingElements()
{
    BindingElementCollection elements = base.CreateBindingElements();

    var securityBindingElement = elements.Find<SecurityBindingElement>();
    elements.Remove(securityBindingElement);
    elements.Add(this.security);

    var transportBindingElement = elements.Find<HttpTransportBindingElement>();
    elements.Remove(transportBindingElement);
    elements.Add(this.transport);

    return elements;
}
```

And it works like a charm!

I can't explain why I need to call base. If someone could explain in the comments, that would be great!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19574170/4339857