# “The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data” error while sending XML string to WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, quota

I have trying everything in three days to fix this error in my application in client and server config, but nothing helps, this is my configs:

Client:

```
public class IdBookIssuerIssuedTokenBinding : WS2007HttpBinding
{
    private readonly HttpTransportBindingElement transport;
    private readonly SecurityBindingElement security;

    public IdBookIssuerIssuedTokenBinding(EndpointAddress bindingAddress)
    {
        WS2007HttpBinding ws2007HttpBinding = new WS2007HttpBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);
        ws2007HttpBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;
        ws2007HttpBinding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;

        //TODO: expose somewhere to configure this timeouts
        ws2007HttpBinding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        ws2007HttpBinding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

        ws2007HttpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
        ws2007HttpBinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = int.MaxValue;
        ws2007HttpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = int.MaxValue;
        ws2007HttpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = int.MaxValue;
        ws2007HttpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = int.MaxValue;
        ws2007HttpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = int.MaxValue;
        ws2007HttpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = int.MaxValue;

        this.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = int.MaxValue;
        this.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = int.MaxValue;
        this.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = int.MaxValue;
        this.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = int.MaxValue;
        this.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = int.MaxValue;

        IssuedSecurityTokenParameters securityTokenParameters = new System.ServiceModel.Security.Tokens.IssuedSecurityTokenParameters(
            "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV1.1",
                bindingAddress,
                ws2007HttpBinding);

        security = SecurityBindingElement.CreateIssuedTokenOverTransportBindingElement(securityTokenParameters);
        security.MessageSecurityVersion = MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity11WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10;

        transport = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
        transport.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
        transport.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
        transport.MaxBufferPoolSize = int.MaxValue;

        this.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Text;
        this.MaxBufferPoolSize = int.MaxValue;
        this.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
    }

    public override BindingElementCollection CreateBindingElements()
    {
        BindingElementCollection elements = new BindingElementCollection();

        elements.Add(this.security);
        elements.Add(this.transport);

        return elements;
    }
}

public class ClientFactory
{
    #region static

    private readonly static ClientFactory _current;

    static ClientFactory()
    {
        _current = new ClientFactory();
    }

    public static ClientFactory Current { get { return _current; } }

    #endregion

    private ClientFactory()
    { }

    public TClient Create<TClient, TServiceInterface>(string businessEntityContainerName, string userName, string password) 
            where TClient : ClientBase<TServiceInterface>, new()
            where TServiceInterface : class
    {
        var client = new TClient();
        return this.Create<TClient, TServiceInterface>(client, businessEntityContainerName, userName, password);
    }

    public TClient Create<TClient, TServiceInterface>(string businessEntityContainerName, string userName, string password, Binding stsBinding, EndpointAddress remoteServiceAddress)
            where TClient : ClientBase<TServiceInterface>, new()
            where TServiceInterface : class
    {
        var client = (TClient)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TClient), stsBinding, remoteServiceAddress);
        return this.Create<TClient, TServiceInterface>(client, businessEntityContainerName, userName, password);
    }

    public TClient Create<TClient, TServiceInterface>(string businessEntityContainerName, string userName, string password, EndpointAddress stsAddress, EndpointAddress remoteServiceAddress)
            where TClient : ClientBase<TServiceInterface>, new()
            where TServiceInterface : class
    {
        IdBookIssuerIssuedTokenBinding binding = new IdBookIssuerIssuedTokenBinding(stsAddress);

        var client = (TClient)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TClient), binding, remoteServiceAddress);
        return this.Create<TClient, TServiceInterface>(client, businessEntityContainerName, userName, password);
    }

    private TClient Create<TClient, TServiceInterface>(TClient client, string businessEntityContainerName, string userName, string password)
            where TClient : ClientBase<TServiceInterface>, new()
            where TServiceInterface : class
    {
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = userName;
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = password;

        //TODO: expose somewhere to configure this timeouts
        var binding = (IdBookIssuerIssuedTokenBinding)client.Endpoint.Binding;
        binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
        binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = int.MaxValue;
        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = int.MaxValue;
        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = int.MaxValue;
        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = int.MaxValue;
        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = int.MaxValue;

        client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new HeaderInfoBehavior(businessEntityContainerName));

        foreach (var operation in client.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Contract.Operations)
        {
            var dtSerializerOp = operation.Behaviors.Find<DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior>();

            dtSerializerOp.DataContractResolver =
                    new DynamicTypeResolver(typeof(TClient).Assembly, typeof(TClient).Namespace);

            dtSerializerOp.MaxItemsInObjectGraph = int.MaxValue;
        }

        return client;
    }
}
```

Service:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="Services">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
      <httpRuntime executionTimeout="4800" maxRequestLength="2097150"/>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="errorHandler" type="GILabs.MetaFx.Application.Service.Commom.ErrorHandlerBehavior, GILabs.MetaFx.Application.Service.Commom" />
        <add name="federatedServiceHostConfiguration" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Configuration.ConfigureServiceHostBehaviorExtensionElement, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WsServiceBehavior">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
          <errorHandler />
          <federatedServiceHostConfiguration />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>

      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WsServiceBehavior">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WsHttpEndpointBinding">
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
      <ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
        <binding name="IDBookIssuerIssuedTokenFederation" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00"
          receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
          transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text"
          textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
            maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />

          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message establishSecurityContext="false">
              <issuer address="https://localhost/idbook/Services/SecurityToken.svc" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="IDBookIssuerIssuedToken" />
            </message>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
      <ws2007HttpBinding>
        <binding name="IDBookIssuerUsernameMixed">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" establishSecurityContext="false" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </ws2007HttpBinding>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="IDBookIssuerIssuedToken">
          <security authenticationMode="IssuedTokenOverTransport"
                    messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10">
            <issuedTokenParameters>
              <issuer address="https://localhost/idbook/Services/SecurityToken.svc"
                      binding="ws2007HttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="IDBookIssuerUsernameMixed">
              </issuer>
            </issuedTokenParameters>
          </security>
          <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="2147483647" maxWritePoolSize="2147483647">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
              maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          </textMessageEncoding>
          <httpTransport maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
            maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WsServiceBehavior" name="GILabs.MetaFx.Application.MetadataService.MetaService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="ws2007FederationHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="IDBookIssuerIssuedTokenFederation"
          name="MetadataWsHttpEndpoint" contract="GILabs.MetaFx.Application.MetadataService.IMetadataService">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WsServiceBehavior" name="GILabs.MetaFx.Application.Service.AppService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="ws2007FederationHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="IDBookIssuerIssuedTokenFederation"
          name="ApplicationWsHttpEndpoint" contract="GILabs.MetaFx.Application.Service.IAppService">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WsServiceBehavior" name="GILabs.MetaFx.Application.Service.SyncChangeService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="ws2007FederationHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="IDBookIssuerIssuedTokenFederation"
          name="ApplicationWsHttpEndpoint" contract="GILabs.MetaFx.Application.Service.ISyncChangeService">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true"
                      logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
                      logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
                      logMalformedMessages="true"
                      maxMessagesToLog="5000"
                      maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2000">
      </messageLogging>
    </diagnostics>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.webServer>

    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="500000000"></requestLimits>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="All" propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="C:\temp\Traces.svclog"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <trace autoflush ="true" />
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Creating my service in Client:

```
_syncChangeService = ClientFactory.Current.Create<SyncChangeServiceClient, ISyncChangeService>(
                         ConfigurationManager.Instance.OrganizationName,
                         ConfigurationManager.Instance.ServiceManagerUserName,
                         ConfigurationManager.Instance.ServiceManagerUserPassword,
                         new EndpointAddress(ConfigurationManager.Instance.IdBookWSUrl),
                         new EndpointAddress(string.Format("{0}/Services/SyncChange.svc", ConfigurationManager.Instance.ServiceManagerUrl))
                     );
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the code where you create the client and get this error?

Comment: @Tim yes, look at update.

Comment: Have you verified that `ConfigurationManager.Instance.IdBookWSUrl` is returning an instance of `IdBookIssuerIssuedTokenBinding`?

Comment: IdBookWsUrl don't return IdBookIssuerIssuedTokenBinding, this return the url string of the IdBook Endpoint: configProps.GetItem("IdBookWSUrl").Value = "https://localhost/IdBook/Services/SecurityToken.svc";

Comment: Right - I wrote my comment in a rush so was unclear.  What I meant to say was that in the Create overload, when you use that address to call the token service, does it return an instance of `IdBookIssuerIssuedTokenBinding`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem! :D

The problem is in `IdBookIssuerIssuedTokenBinding.CreateBindingElements()`.

I had overridden and not called the base:

```
public override BindingElementCollection CreateBindingElements()
{
    BindingElementCollection elements = new BindingElementCollection();

    elements.Add(this.security);
    elements.Add(this.transport);

    return elements;
}
```

Now I am doing this:

```
public override BindingElementCollection CreateBindingElements()
{
    BindingElementCollection elements = base.CreateBindingElements();

    var securityBindingElement = elements.Find<SecurityBindingElement>();
    elements.Remove(securityBindingElement);
    elements.Add(this.security);

    var transportBindingElement = elements.Find<HttpTransportBindingElement>();
    elements.Remove(transportBindingElement);
    elements.Add(this.transport);

    return elements;
}
```

And it works like a charm!

I can't explain why I need to call base. If someone could explain in the comments, that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

I've run into problems similar to this before. In your config file, try increasing the size for all instances of your following line (there were at least two):

```
ws2007HttpBinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = int.MaxValue;
```

Also, in your service, do the same here:

```
<ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
    <binding name="IDBookIssuerIssuedTokenFederation" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" 
... **maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"**
```

It's a wee bit counter-intuitive, but the service will barf if it receives a response that is larger than it is configured to accept.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hey, I have already increase the value of MaxBufferPoolSize in client and service configuration. Look at my code.